# SELECT FOR UPDATE to lock database during migration

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, transactions

I'm trying to block concurrent modification during database migration, my approach is to lock an existing table `t` (prereq) using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and achieve migration during lock.

Thus I created a simple sample like following:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb", "root", "");

conn.setAutoCommit(false);
statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM t FOR UPDATE");
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));

System.out.println("Sleeping...");
Thread.sleep(10000);

statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE t2 (id int PRIMARY KEY)");
// Release lock
statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE t SET id = 2 WHERE id = 1");

conn.commit();

statement.close();
conn.close();
```

where `t` is a dummy table with only `id int PRIMARY KEY`.

I set a `Thread.sleep(10000);` to simulate long process. During the `Thread.sleep(10000);` I'm running a second (similar piece of code) to simulate concurrency

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb", "root", "");

Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM t FOR UPDATE");
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));

conn.commit();

statement.close();
conn.close();
```

But I expected that code print `2`.. it printed `1`.

When I checking MySQL general log I see that thing

```
438 Query   SET autocommit=0
438 Query   SELECT id FROM t FOR UPDATE
439 Query   /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.35 ( Revision: 5fb9c5849535c13917c2cf9baaece6ef9693ef27 ) */SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 'net_write_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_connection' OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' OR Variable_name = 'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'lower_case_table_names' OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 'sql_mode' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' OR Variable_name = 'license' OR Variable_name = 'init_connect'
439 Query   /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.35 ( Revision: 5fb9c5849535c13917c2cf9baaece6ef9693ef27 ) */SELECT @@session.auto_increment_increment
439 Query   SET character_set_results = NULL
439 Query   SET autocommit=1
439 Query   SET sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
439 Query   SET autocommit=0
439 Query   SELECT id FROM t FOR UPDATE
438 Query   CREATE TABLE t2 (id int PRIMARY KEY)
439 Query   commit
439 Query   rollback
439 Quit    
438 Query   UPDATE t SET id = 2 WHERE id = 1
438 Query   commit
438 Query   rollback
```

After `CREATE TABLE t2...` transaction (session 2) is commited that release lock, but I'm in `autoCommit(false)` why MySQL force `commit` on this case.

I may also missunderstand how `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` works...

---

**UPDATE: tested without Java and JDBC using mysql client**

```
SESSION1> CREATE TABLE t (id int PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=INNODB;
SESSION1> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
SESSION1> BEGIN;
SESSION1> SELECT id FROM t FOR UPDATE;

SESSION2> BEGIN;
SESSION2> SELECT id FROM t FOR UPDATE;
--> HERE SESSION2 is stuck (expected behavior)

SESSION1> CREATE TABLE t2 (id int PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=INNODB;
--> HERE SESSION2 is unlock returning 
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (4.15 sec)
```

It seems to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` with DLL statement does not works as I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's not possible to create DLL statement like `CREATE TABLE` during exclusive lock (`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`).

However to perform my needs I will use the same strategy as [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/). Indeed flyway uses two sessions:

1. Metatable session to lock (Metatable is core table for flyway)
2. Object session to perform migration

Thus with different session locking mechanism works, can be simulated using mysql cli

```
SESSION-METATABLE> CREATE TABLE t (id int PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=INNODB;
SESSION-METATABLE> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
SESSION-METATABLE> BEGIN;
SESSION-METATABLE> SELECT id FROM t FOR UPDATE;

SESSION-CONCURRENT> BEGIN;
SESSION-CONCURRENT> SELECT id FROM t FOR UPDATE;
--> HERE SESSION-CONCURRENT is stuck (expected behavior)

SESSION-OBJECT> BEGIN;
SESSION-OBJECT> CREATE TABLE t2 (id int PRIMARY KEY);
--> HERE SESSION-CONCURRENT is not unlock
SESSION-OBJECT> COMMIT;
--> SESSION-CONCURRENT still stuck even after COMMIT;

SESSION-METATABLE>UPDATE t SET id=2 WHERE id=1;
SESSION-METATABLE>COMMIT;
--> HERE SESSION-CONCURRENT is unlock and print
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
1 row in set (23.33 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will observe this behavior if your storage engine is MyISAM. MyISAM doesn't support transactions, as a result, your first code is not gonna put any locks as all statements are automatically committed, so your second code will happily swim through their own SELECT FOR UPDATE and proceed straight to SELECT ID.

Long story short: Switch your database to InnoDB storage to make it work.

References:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html

Comment: Yeah but both tables are using innodb. And second `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is really stuck during `Thread.sleep` until first session create table

Comment: I just edited my question to add more information. And I'm using innodb (forced in mysql cli example) it's default on my MySQL 5.6